# Mongodb log show they're using IXScan but db.currentOp() no

Tags: mongodb, indexing

On mongodb log shows they're using IXScan

> [conn37225] command hone.$cmd command: count { count: "events", query:
>   { eventName: "Started", createdAt: { $gt: new Date(1449789260690),
>   $lte: new Date(1450221260693) }, data.quizId:
>   "54fe05f26aa23aeb72e3fdbb" }, fields: null } planSummary: IXSCAN {
>   createdAt: 1, data.quizId: 1, eventName: 1 } keyUpdates:0
>   numYields:4279 locks(micros) r:53800992 reslen:48 38679ms

but on `db.currentOp()` don't

```
{
        "opid" : 4719819,
        "active" : true,
        "secs_running" : 4,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(4221829),
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "hone.events",
        "query" : {
                "count" : "events",
                "query" : {
                        "eventName" : "Started",
                        "createdAt" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2015-12-10T23:14:20.690Z"),
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2015-12-15T23:14:20.693Z")
                        },
                        "data.quizId" : "54fe05f26aa23aeb72e3fdbb"
                },
                "fields" : null
        },
        "client" : "10.8.0.7:43823",
        "desc" : "conn37225",
        "threadId" : "0x7f60aee9a700",
        "connectionId" : 37225,
        "locks" : {
                "^" : "r",
                "^hone" : "R"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "numYields" : 384,
        "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                        "r" : NumberLong(6417513),
                        "w" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                        "r" : NumberLong(800491),
                        "w" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
```

Is the mongodb using properly the `{ createdAt: 1, data.quizId: 1, eventName: 1 }` index?

using `hint()` with `explain()` is possible see the difference. 
with `hint()` use specifically that index and works fast.

I'm wondering know what is causing it to be slower.

**Without hint**

```
> db.events.find({ eventName: "Completed", createdAt: { $gt: new Date(1449945185127), $lte: new Date(1450377185140) }, "data.quizId": "55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54" }).explain("executionStats")
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor createdAt_1_data.quizId_1_eventName_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 2519326,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2543445,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 7536363,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 79008,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 74443,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "createdAt" : [
                        [
                                ISODate("2015-12-12T18:33:05.127Z"),
                                ISODate("2015-12-17T18:33:05.140Z")
                        ]
                ],
                "data.quizId" : [
                        [
                                "55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54",
                                "55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54"
                        ]
                ],
                "eventName" : [
                        [
                                "Completed",
                                "Completed"
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "allPlans" : [
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor createdAt_1_data.quizId_1_eventName_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 0,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                        "nscanned" : 2519326,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "createdAt" : [
                                        [
                                                ISODate("2015-12-12T18:33:05.127Z"),
                                                ISODate("2015-12-17T18:33:05.140Z")
                                        ]
                                ],
                                "data.quizId" : [
                                        [
                                                "55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54",
                                                "55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54"
                                        ]
                                ],
                                "eventName" : [
                                        [
                                                "Completed",
                                                "Completed"
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor eventName_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 0,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 2497710,
                        "nscanned" : 2497710,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "eventName" : [
                                        [
                                                "Completed",
                                                "Completed"
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor createdAt_1_data.questionId_1_eventName_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 0,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 45735,
                        "nscanned" : 2519327,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "createdAt" : [
                                        [
                                                ISODate("2015-12-12T18:33:05.127Z"),
                                                ISODate("2015-12-17T18:33:05.140Z")
                                        ]
                                ],
                                "data.questionId" : [
                                        [
                                                {
                                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                                }
                                        ]
                                ],
                                "eventName" : [
                                        [
                                                "Completed",
                                                "Completed"
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "server" : "mongodb-05:27017",
        "filterSet" : false,
        "stats" : {
                "type" : "FETCH",
                "works" : 2519328,
                "yields" : 79008,
                "unyields" : 79008,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 0,
                "needTime" : 2519326,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "forcedFetches" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0,
                "children" : [
                        {
                                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                                "works" : 2519327,
                                "yields" : 79008,
                                "unyields" : 79008,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "advanced" : 0,
                                "needTime" : 2519326,
                                "needFetch" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "keyPattern" : "{ createdAt: 1, data.quizId: 1, eventName: 1 }",
                                "isMultiKey" : 0,
                                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['createdAt']: (new Date(1449945185127), new Date(1450377185140)], field #1['data.quizId']: [\"55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54\", \"55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54\"], field #2['eventName']: [\"Completed\", \"Completed\"]",
                                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                "matchTested" : 0,
                                "keysExamined" : 2519326,
                                "children" : [ ]
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

**With hint**

```
> db.events.find({ eventName: "Completed", createdAt: { $gt: new Date(1449945185127), $lte: new Date(1450377185140) }, "data.quizId": "55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54" }).hint('createdAt_1_data.quizId_1_eventName_1').explain("executionStats")
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor createdAt_1_data.quizId_1_eventName_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 2519326,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 2519326,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 19682,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 8211,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "createdAt" : [
                        [
                                ISODate("2015-12-12T18:33:05.127Z"),
                                ISODate("2015-12-17T18:33:05.140Z")
                        ]
                ],
                "data.quizId" : [
                        [
                                "55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54",
                                "55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54"
                        ]
                ],
                "eventName" : [
                        [
                                "Completed",
                                "Completed"
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "allPlans" : [
                {
                        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor createdAt_1_data.quizId_1_eventName_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "n" : 0,
                        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
                        "nscanned" : 2519326,
                        "scanAndOrder" : false,
                        "indexOnly" : false,
                        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
                        "indexBounds" : {
                                "createdAt" : [
                                        [
                                                ISODate("2015-12-12T18:33:05.127Z"),
                                                ISODate("2015-12-17T18:33:05.140Z")
                                        ]
                                ],
                                "data.quizId" : [
                                        [
                                                "55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54",
                                                "55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54"
                                        ]
                                ],
                                "eventName" : [
                                        [
                                                "Completed",
                                                "Completed"
                                        ]
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "server" : "mongodb-05:27017",
        "filterSet" : false,
        "stats" : {
                "type" : "FETCH",
                "works" : 2519327,
                "yields" : 19682,
                "unyields" : 19682,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 0,
                "needTime" : 2519326,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "forcedFetches" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0,
                "children" : [
                        {
                                "type" : "IXSCAN",
                                "works" : 2519327,
                                "yields" : 19682,
                                "unyields" : 19682,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "advanced" : 0,
                                "needTime" : 2519326,
                                "needFetch" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "keyPattern" : "{ createdAt: 1, data.quizId: 1, eventName: 1 }",
                                "isMultiKey" : 0,
                                "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['createdAt']: (new Date(1449945185127), new Date(1450377185140)], field #1['data.quizId']: [\"55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54\", \"55ce6dde5239249a70f9ef54\"], field #2['eventName']: [\"Completed\", \"Completed\"]",
                                "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                "matchTested" : 0,
                                "keysExamined" : 2519326,
                                "children" : [ ]
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Comment: you should use `explain("executionStats")` to check if mongodb using index properly not the log nor current op )https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/explain-results/#executionstats)

Comment: Greetings @somallg, just update the question with `explain("executionStats")` as you suggest